# How to declare a function with an unknown parameter datatype in a header file?

Tags: c, function, header-files, extern

I am pretty new to C and have the following issue with a framework specific datatype that is used within an extern declared function for a parameter inside a header file.

```
//FILE: example.h

extern void my_function(void *);
```

```
//FILE: example.c

#include "example.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"

void my_function(TaskHandle_t _taskHandle){
 //function body
}
```

The datatype `TaskHandle_t`  is of course not known in the header as I would have to include the freertos header here as well. I heard including other header files inside a header file is bad practise.

If I try to compile the example above the following error raises:

```
error: conflicting types for 'my_function'
 void my_function(TaskHandle_t _taskHandle)
```

Whats the best approach to solve this problem?

Comment: "I heard including other header files inside a header file is bad practise." Where? The rule is "include what you need, do not include what you do not need".

Comment: If you know exactly what the alias `TaskHandle_t` refers to, then you could forward declare it in the header file. Otherwise you must include the header file that defines the type in your own header file.

Comment: @M.Oehm You deleted you comment, would you like me to delete the quote from my answer?

Comment: As an addendum to my comment: The forward declaration solution is very fragile. If the definition of the type-alias changes you need to update your code as well. As others have said and answered, Include what you need when you need it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I kind of picked up your comment, but without writing the "define yourself" part. I rather imply to later include the header which cleanly define it. Let me know if you want me to change my answer with respect to your input.

Comment: "Bad practice" depends on the circumstances. What's bad for a large project may be acceptable for a small one (but need a refactoring if, unexpectedly, the small one grows large ;-) ).

Comment: From your post it is not clear whether `example.h`  is under your control (and you can change it), or whether it is part of a 3rd-party framework you are *using* (and cannot/should not change). If you can change it, forward-declare `TaskHandle_t ` and declare the function to take a pointer to that type. That is indeed preferred to including entire headers because it reduces coupling between files and modules. If you have to use the header as-is, with a `void *` parameter, define your implementation the same way and cast the pointer inside the function to  `TaskHandle_t ` .

Comment: @Yunnosch Your answer is good. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring an otherwise unknown datatype is about the only good reason why you should include a header in a header. However there is also the so-called 'forward declaration', which you can use when you need to pass a pointer to a struct. (Or class in C++)

A forward declaration simply looks like this:

```
//.h file
struct YourType;
void yourFunction(struct YourType *variable);

//.c file
#include "HeaderContainingYourType.h"

void yourFunction(struct YourType *variable)
{
}
```

As for your specific problem, your prototype and your declaration must have the exact same signature, so if you declare the prototype with `void *`, you must use `void *` in the declaration too.

Ways to solve your problem:

- Include the header file you need.
- Pull out the typedef from the header file and redeclare it verbatim in your new header file.
- Pass `void *` and cast it to the appropriate type in the C file.

Please note, that the third approach negates the aspect of 'typesafety', since you can pass anything to a `void *`.

Answer (score 2):

Very much in contrast to the best practice you mention, I follow what I consider a rule:

"Include what you need. Do not include what you do not need."

I am very much with M. Oehm:

> If a header file requires definitions from other header files, it should include that header. It sure isn't any worse practice than trying to work around it by using void *.

The concept of forward declaring structs allows to use pointer-to-that before including or typedefining the struct in detail. (As mentioned in the comment be some programmer dude.)

Answer (score 0):

If `TaskHandle_t` is a pointer to struct then you can forward declare the struct and add an alias for a pointer to it.

```
typedef struct TaskHandle_s *TaskHandle_t;
void my_function(TaskHandle_t _taskHandle);
```